# Function import that returns object instead of complex type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm building dynamic table with stored procedure, so when adding function import, I want it to return object instead of specific type. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

UDPATE

I've tested this and it doesn't work - the call to `SqlQuery` returns a `System.Object`. I'll not mark for deletion as it is useful to know that this technique doesn't work.

---

it should be possible but as @BorisB has said, I'm not sure why you would want to ...

```
List<dynamic> result = context
    .Database
    .SqlQuery<dynamic>("select * from ......")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I want this data serialized as JSON to use with JavaScript later on client side

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible what would be the type of that returned object and how would you access its properties?

You'd somehow had to build an EF complex type and a function import at runtime or build a model using ModelBuilder (but you still don't have a data class), which *may* be possible in theory but it in practice it is way above the problem you are solving.

Maybe it would be better to use ADO.Net directly or modify those SPs to return results as XML which is then consumed by the client (but in XML case you still don't have compiled type of returned objects, so no deserialization, only XPath).